# $ is not a function but jQuery is loaded when adding JavaScript to a custom theme

Tags: 8, javascript

I must have something set up incorrectly in my custom theme. jQuery is loading and works fine elsewhere on the same page in a views slideshow using jquery.cycle. My custom JavaScript however reports that `$` is not a function.

The info.yml file includes the global-scripts property.

The libraries.yml file contains the following code.

```
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

The content of js/script.js is the following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('load scroll', function () {
        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('#layer-1').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + -(scrolled * 0.25) + 'px, 0)'); // parallax (25% scroll rate)
    });
});
```

The first line in script.js returns the error in the console. It is the only error I receive.

I checked the page source and confirmed that jQuery is being loaded before script.js at the bottom of the page below the footer.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Drupal js documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview) states

> Note: Since Drupal uses jQuery.noConflict() and only loads JavaScript
>   files when required, to use jQuery and the $ shortcode for jQuery you
>   must include jQuery and Drupal as dependencies in the library
>   definition in your MODULE.libraries.yml and add a wrapper around your
>   function.

You should also use behaviors instead of `document.ready()` which is stated earlier in the above documentation.

> However with Drupal there is an alternate better method [to `document.ready()`]; using the
>   functionality of `Drupal.behaviors` and `once()`. If used properly this
>   will ensure that your code runs both on normal page loads and when
>   data is loaded by AJAX (or BigPipe!) - but not jQuery methods like
>   `load()` which should be avoided as Drupal behaviors will fail to load
>   for loading functions other than `ajax()`.

So your snippet should look like:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(window).once().on('load scroll', function () {
        // ...
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

If your selector is something other than `window`, e.g. a class, you should update it to be something like `$('.my-class', context).once().etc`. Passing context like this ensures that your js only fires if the element exists in the currently being loaded context, i.e. if a small chunk of the page is loaded via ajax context will only contain that small chunk of the page. `.once()` ensures the js will only be added to the element once. It will prevent scenarios where you single click an element but it acts as though you double or triple clicked it. Here is the [documentation for .once()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-once).

Comment: The linked page has the answer, but it's not related to document ready (although that needs fixing too).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had a conflict with another module or something. I was able to resolve this issue by wrapping my code like this.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).on('load scroll', function () {
            var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
            $('#layer-1').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + -(scrolled * 0.25) + 'px, 0)'); // parallax (25% scroll rate)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, the last line needs to be `})(jQuery);`